# Android - STICKY_SERVICE restarting flow and testing (null Intent)

Tags: android, android-service

I've recently had some crash where I wasn't handling `Intent==null` in my `onStartCommand` method. Values sent through the Intent are necessary for me and stored only as instance variables. I want to be sure those values will be restored and `GoogleApiClient` started.

I'm unable to restart the service via `adb` or invoke service restart manually (if you know how please write it in your answer `adb shell am start/stopservice` didn't work for me - service not found)

Service documentation:

> ...after creating the new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent object, so you must take care to check for this.

1. Do I understand correctly if I say, that I have to store necessary variables into `SharedPreferences` and start `GoogleApiClient` or do those instance variables and `GoogleApiClient` persists?
2. What exactly happens (which `Service` methods are being called) when service restart occurs?
3. How do test the 'restart' behavior (automatic, manual or via `adb` tools)

Code used before crash:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // ...

    // mGoogleApiClient created in onCreate() exists here
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    // Intent was null here
    mActionInterval = intent.getLongExtra(EXTRA_ACTION_INTERVAL, EXTRA_ACTION_INTERVAL_DEFAULT);
    mUpdateFrequency = intent.getLongExtra(EXTRA_UPDATE_FREQUENCY, EXTRA_UPDATE_FREQUENCY_DEFAULT);

    LogUtils.v(LOG_TAG, "starting GPS Tracker with interval: " + mActionInterval +
            " and update frequency: " + mUpdateFrequency);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer as I'm working on this for now.

I can however give you the adb commands to test the service starting, stopping and restarting scenarios.

ADB Command to send an intent:
    adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.demo.action.LAUNCH

In my solution I have a listener for start and stop intents. You can simply attempt to restart the service by stopping and starting immediately.

As far as variable saving and the exact mechanism of restarting I have yet to find explanatory information other than the proper docs I'm struggling to understand properly.